# Отсутствие запятой перед "что " и "когда"

Tags: пунктуация

«Они, наверное, давние друзья. Во всяком случае, Кауфман может видеть девушку   **когда** пожелает. Вероятно, этот тип считает, что имеет на это право. Тем более  **что** она с отцом часто переезжала с места на место».

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему отсутствуют запятые?

Comment: @shampar "текст курсивомзяпятые?"...   Переводчика смогу "дать" только завтра.

Comment: @Galina Avanesova Корректорский профессионализм Вам не изменяет. ПОМНЮ  "Вашу" точку внутри кавычек. С уважением кланяюсь.

Comment: А я правильно убрала к чертям "текст курсивомзяпятые"? Иль оне хранили сакральный смысл?)))

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Да-да, конечно. Какая уж тут сакральность?..  Только опять я  "на распутье" с этой запятой.

Comment: А чиво? Чиво тута распутничать? *Тем более что* - нерасчленяемый союз; *видеть когда пожелает* - см. коммент Людмилы; я бы поставила запятуху, как сказала Сиби.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Кауфман может видеть девушку, **когда пожелает.**

Здесь я бы поставила запятую, предложение имеет структуру обычного придаточного.

2) **Тем более что** она с отцом часто переезжала с места на место.

**Как уже сказано**,  "тем более что" - **составной нерасчленяемый союз**, нет запятой перед ЧТО.

В данном случае союз является присоединительным, а вообще он используется в сложноподчиненных предложениях с придаточным причины и выражает  отношение логического обоснования (причинно-аргументирующие): Мы заедем к друзьям за вещами, **тем более что** нам по дороге.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний, например **приглашу к себе кого пожелаю**  ([Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm)).

Составные подчинительные союзы *как если бы; меж / между тем как; потому как; словно как; так что* (в значении следствия); ***тем более что***; тогда как не расчленяются (т. е. запятая между частями союза не ставится).

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3

Comment: Очень хочется поставить запятую перед "когда".  Мне кажется, что предложение имеет такой смысл: "Во всяком случае, Кауфман может видеть девушку [тогда], когда пожелает".

Comment: Значение фразы с запятой меняется - упор на обстоятельство времени тогда, а без запятой значение "всегда, в любой момент", это неразложимое сочетание, как и кого пожелаю = любого, а с запятой - того, кого сейчас пожелаю, а завтра другого.